# Oracle ORA_HASH alternative in Postgres(MD5)

Tags: postgresql, oracle

I am trying to find an alternative to the ORA_HASH Oracle function in Postgres(edb). I know there are hashtext() and MD5(). Hashtext should be ideal, but it's not documented and so I can't use it for some reasons. I'd like to know if there is any way of using MD5() and getting the same value that you'd get in ORA_HASH giving the same value for both of them.

For example, this is how I use it and what I get in Oracle:

```
SELECT ORA_HASH('huyu') FROM dual;
----------------------------------
3284595515
```

I'd like to do something similar in postgres, so that if I pass the '*huyu*' value, I'd get the exact same '*3284595515*' value.

Now, I know that ORA_HASH restores a **number** and MD5 restores **hexadecimal** value. I think I'd need the function that converts the hexadecimal 32 into a number, but I can't get the same value and I'm not sure if it is possible.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions

Comment: I'd say ORA_HASH  is very old Oracle's proprietary hashing function, which is also used internally by the database.  If you search through internet, you will somewhere find what its C function name and its disassembly. ORA_HASH is quite simple hashing algorithm invented before photographically safe hashing functions were introduced.

Comment: MD5 is a standard hashing algorithm that is likely to be available most anywhere you go.  You should be able to get Oracle's `dbms_crypto` package's MD5 hash to match PostgreSQL's MD5 hash (or any other language/ framework/ database's MD5 hash).  Could you have Oracle use a standard hash algorithm rather than `ora_hash`?

Comment: I cant change the use of ora_hash in what I need to do, unfortunately. That's why I am asking this specific case, because I have to deal with this specific problem(

Comment: Seems that this problem hasn't been solved yet, due to proprietary software issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948266/what-is-the-algorithm-used-by-the-ora-hash-function    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64578376/how-to-replace-ora-hash-function-of-oracle-in-postgres

Answer (score 1):

If you rely on the exact implementation of `ORA_HASH`, which is a proprietary hash function in a closed-source software, you are locked to this vendor, sorry.

I don't see how using PostgreSQL's `hashtext` is worse than `ORA_HASH`: it is documented (in the source), it's implementation is public, and it is not going to be removed, because it is required for hash partitioning.

Comment: The use of hashtext() is a simple "burocratic" problem in my case, so I wanted to be sure there is no alternative